# How to make the scale continuous in this facet plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I am a still learning and trying to create a facet plot. I have try googling it but I can't find the right solution for it.

This is the code I used for the plot

```r
met_ven %>%
  pivot_longer(c(14, 15, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27, 32, 33, 34),names_to="metabolites",values_to="Concentration") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(Day),y=Concentration)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_wrap(~metabolites, scales = "free", ncol = 3) +
  labs(title = "Venison")
```

The plot is showing a concentration of metabolites (y) at certain time point(x) variable are 0, 0.25, 0.79 1.25, 1.75 and 2.25.

From this code the plot giving me

[image: Plot]

From my understanding, using factor(Day) would put the Day in discrete but I dont want that. I want to do a box plot on a continuous scale.. but if I remove that ti x=Day

```
ggplot(aes(x=(Day),y=Concentration))
```

I get this

[image]

I want the plot to be like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvUaL.png) on a continuous scale

Answer (score 1):

If you want boxplots on a continuous scale, you'd have to set the `group` aesthetic appropriately. Example without group:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = sample(1:5, 30, replace = TRUE),
  y = runif(30)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_boxplot()
#> Warning: Continuous x aesthetic -- did you forget aes(group=...)?
```

[image]

Including the group:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, group = x)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>